# How to make a nested and grouped combination of the elements of the list?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, combinations, permutation

I hope the title of the question is clear, if not here is more details.

```py
lis_a, lis_b, lis_c = ['A', 'C'], ['T', 'G'], ['G', 'T']

# I am trying make combination of these list elements
all_possible_states = [[x, y, z] for x in lis_a for y in lis_b for z in lis_c]
print('all possible states')
```

**Output is:**

```
all possible states
[['A', 'T', 'G'], ['A', 'T', 'T'], ['A', 'G', 'G'], ['A', 'G', 'T'], ['C', 'T', 'G'], ['C', 'T', 'T'], ['C', 'G', 'G'], ['C', 'G', 'T']]
```

I am actually trying to make a combination in a way such that the two complementary combination are also grouped together. 
i.e if 'A' was selected from lis_a with 'T' from lis_b then 'C' from lis_a with 'G' from lis_b would be it's complementary.

**I actually want all possible state in following format where two complementary states are nested together:**

```
[[['A', 'T', 'G'], ['C', 'G', 'T']], [['A', 'T', 'T'], ['C', 'G', 'G']], [['A', 'G', 'G'], [['A', 'G', 'T'], ['C', 'T', 'G']]]

Or,

[(['A', 'T', 'G'], ['C', 'G', 'T']), (['A', 'T', 'T'], ['C', 'G', 'G']), (['A', 'G', 'G'], ['C', 'T', 'T']), (['A', 'G', 'T'], ['C', 'T', 'G'])]
```

Comment: It seems to me that all you want is `list(itertools.product(lis_a, lis_b, lis_c))` unless I'm missing something

Comment: Are you looking for all possible combinations as your example output shows, or complimentary combinations as you say?

Comment: @DeepSpace: The complementary sequence (or states) need be nested together. That the main issue I am facing.

Comment: @GrandPhuba: I want all possible combinations (which is already with list comprehension), but in those all possible combinations I also want the complementary states to be nested together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage the fact that your lists are just *2-tuples* (technically lists of lengths 2) and use binary XOR  `^` to 1 to get the complementary element

```
lis_a, lis_b, lis_c = ['A', 'C'], ['T', 'G'], ['G', 'T']

states = []
for i, x in enumerate(lis_a):
    for j, y in enumerate(lis_b):
        for k, z in enumerate(lis_c):
            state = (x, y, z)
            complement = (lis_a[i^1], lis_b[j^1], lis_c[k^1])
            print(state, complement)
            states.append((state, complement))

# As a comprehension:
# states = [((x, y, z), (lis_a[i^1], lis_b[j^1], lis_c[k^1])) for i, x in enumerate(lis_a) for j, y in enumerate(lis_b) for k, z in enumerate(lis_c)]
```

Output:

```
('A', 'T', 'G') ('C', 'G', 'T')
('A', 'T', 'T') ('C', 'G', 'G')
('A', 'G', 'G') ('C', 'T', 'T')
('A', 'G', 'T') ('C', 'T', 'G')
('C', 'T', 'G') ('A', 'G', 'T')
('C', 'T', 'T') ('A', 'G', 'G')
('C', 'G', 'G') ('A', 'T', 'T')
('C', 'G', 'T') ('A', 'T', 'G')
```

If you want to get a set with no repeated permutations (e.g. the first and last line in the output above), you can use the following:

```
lis_a, lis_b, lis_c = ['A', 'C'], ['T', 'G'], ['G', 'T']
states = []
for num in range(4):
    k, j, i = num & 1, (num >> 1) & 1, (num >> 2) & 1  # 000, 001, 010, 011
    state = lis_a[i], lis_b[j], lis_c[k]
    compliment = lis_a[i ^ 1], lis_b[j ^ 1], lis_c[k ^ 1]
    print(state, compliment)
    states.append((state, compliment))
```

Output:

```
('A', 'T', 'G') ('C', 'G', 'T')
('A', 'T', 'T') ('C', 'G', 'G')
('A', 'G', 'G') ('C', 'T', 'T')
('A', 'G', 'T') ('C', 'T', 'G')
```

Comment: FYI the "binary not" in Python will actually give `-(i+1)` because numbers have no fixed bit width. Your code works, but I think not how you expect. Try these: `~0  # -1` and `~1  # -2`. You would probably prefer `1-i` etc to go between `0` and `1`. Or `i^1` as you chose :)

Comment: @mcskinner thanks for that. Updated to use XOR `x^1` then

Comment: No problem. I submitted an edit for the list comprehension to match. This is a great way to do things if all the input lists are guaranteed to be pairs of complements.

Comment: Already edited it but thanks @mcskinner. One thing also worth nothing is this solution produces duplicates contrary to the desired output of the OP, but I'm keeping the answer in the meantime as it merely build on top of the input provided by the OP.

Comment: I would say, this is one of the great answers I have seen among my questions (including others). Never know that there was a way use `~` and `^` to select the indexes in python. :)

Comment: @GrandPhuba: What kind of duplicates do you mean?

Comment: @everestial007 you're basically still using integers as indices to the list, but you're manipulating the integers using binary operations

Comment: @everestial007 check the first row and last row of the output above `['A', 'T', 'G'] ['C', 'G', 'T']` and `['C', 'G', 'T'] ['A', 'T', 'G']`. If you want these to count as one, then you'll have to use some conditionals, sets, or something to exclude such duplicates.

Comment: i+1 suggest an imaginary number, rite? I have never across the use of ~ and ^ in python before. So, need some reading to do.

Comment: Yes, those two would mean the same.

Comment: No, `i`, `j`, `k` are simply the indices of the current element in the for loop. Notice that I used `enumerate` in the for loops, which provides these indices.

Comment: I see `enumerate` and do understand it well. However, I have never come across an example that used `~` and `^` for selecting from an index.
Currently googling for some examples, but if you can suggest some good example on the use of ~ and ^ that would be great for my knowledge.

Comment: @everestial007 Updated my answer to only have unique combinations. As for `~` aand `^`, they're called bitwise operators, which means it operates on the binary digits of a number. For more information check https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/bitwise_XOR.html

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by canonicalizing each sequence to the minimum of itself and its complement. By taking the minimum you guarantee that a sequence and its complement both map to the same canonicalized representation.

Then you can group by this and find the pairs. A `defaultdict` makes the grouping easy.

```
import collections
import itertools

def canonicalize(seq):
    complements = {'A': 'C', 'C': 'A', 'G': 'T', 'T': 'G'}
    comp = tuple(complements[o] for o in seq)
    return min(seq, comp)

grouped = collections.defaultdict(list)
for seq in itertools.product(lis_a, lis_b, lis_c):
    grouped[canonicalize(seq)].append(seq)

list(grouped.values())
# [[('A', 'T', 'G'), ('C', 'G', 'T')],
#  [('A', 'T', 'T'), ('C', 'G', 'G')],
#  [('A', 'G', 'G'), ('C', 'T', 'T')],
#  [('A', 'G', 'T'), ('C', 'T', 'G')]]
```

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at itertools.combinations:

```
itertools.combinations(iterable, r)
```

Return r length subsequences of elements from the input iterable.

Combinations are emitted in lexicographic sort order. So, if the input iterable is sorted, the combination tuples will be produced in sorted order.

Comment: What is r? Please provide more details.

Comment: iterable is would be 'ACTG'
and r would be 3

Simple Example:
    print(list(combinations('12345',2)))
    [('1', '2'), ('1', '3'), ('1', '4'), ('1', '5'), ('2', '3'), ('2', '4'), ('2', '5'), ('3', '4'), ('3', '5'), ('4', '5')]